# How to choose a default value for a DataGridView ComboBox column from the ComboBox values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, default-value

So here's what I have: A `DataGridView` with a `ComboBox` cell, which is `DataBound` to an `ArrayList` of items. The `ComboBox` is populated properly. What I want is to set the `ComboBox` to one of its items after it has been populated. Is there any way to do this ? Here is the `ComboBox` population method:

```
public void PopulateAssignToComboBox(ArrayList members)
    {
        _editForm.cb_editAssignTo.Items.Clear();
        var source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = members;
        col_assignedToTemplate.DataSource = source;
    }
```

Comment: find the ItemIndex of the particular item and set the item to that index for example if the combox Item you want is in the 3 position in the drom down set the combox.SelectedIndex = 2;

Comment: It is not a regular `ComboBox`, its a `ComboBoxColumn`, so it does not have the SelectedIndex property I am afraid.

Comment: here check out this link then http://cid-c23746227866488d.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/BindingDataGridViewComboBox.zip

Answer (score 1):

Set that property on the <strike>`members`</strike> grid's data to the value you want and the grid will sync with it. Don't manipulate UI elements programmatically, manipulate the bound data. The combobox doesn't exist unless the cell is selected anyway - it is overlayed when the cell is active. You can access the combobox in the EditingControlShowing event, but as I said, this is a poor approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Data Binding, can you clarify a bit more how to achieve this ? I will be grateful!

Comment: I have a [VB.Net Example](http://www.contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) of binding a grid with comboboxes that may help you understand that the combobox columns will automatically show the correct value if you bind your data correctly.